# Mime type issues with build folder - React Express App

Tags: reactjs, express, build, mime-types

I had a website deployed and working well until yesterday. It is a react app using express and NodeJS.

My website is still working well in developpement using yarn start, but in production i am getting theses errors :

```
GEThttps://www.mysite.fr/static/js/main.fd67b0bb.js
GEThttps://www.mysite.fr/static/css/main.43a07738.css
La ressource à l’adresse « https://www.mysite.fr/static/css/main.43a07738.css » a été bloquée en raison d’un type MIME (« text/html ») incorrect (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). //MIME TYPE issues
La ressource à l’adresse « https://www.mysite.fr/static/js/main.fd67b0bb.js » a été bloquée en raison d’un type MIME (« text/html ») incorrect (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

Does someone ever encountered this issue ? I had Google too much hours without finding anything working...

Here is my app.js code :

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");
var cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

//I skipped the res.setHeader part...

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(9000);
```

Any idea on what is happening here ?

Comment: A lot of answers I saw googling were talking about wrong folders errors, but it doesn't help

Comment: If I try to follow these steps https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing, I am getting this error then : "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement main.9ffd4fc2.js:2:578note: { opened at line 2, column 480"

Answer (score 0):

I think you use live server.
So, try not to open your site with it.
use the simple way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).